# jQuery Charting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, charts

Can anybody suggest nice cross browser **jQuery** **API** **plugin** for developing Chart application

except like filamentgroup.com.

The API should be customizible.I want to integrate it in **ASP.NET**. (ofcourse 
ASP.NET 3.5 comes with inbuilt Chart control,I want some nice jQuery Plugins).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**I've used these with success (customizable, cross-browser, etc):**

- [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)
- [jQPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)

**Others I've come across:**

- [Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/)
- [jQChart](http://www.jqchart.com/)

Comment: Actually had these delicious'd

Comment: @brianng. How does jQPlot compare with Flot? Which would you use if you started a new project today?

Comment: @nosredna Ever since I used jQPlot, I've used it exclusively. I like the extensibility and great documentation. At the end of the day, it's about being able to create the graphs that I've needed and jQPlot has worked out better for my projects. HTH :)

Comment: Will it supports even mobile browsers?

Comment: @rengaseshan I've only tested it in the iPhone (which worked fine), not sure about the others.

Comment: if i am not so inquisitive ,is it possible to get iPhone simulator somewhere for testing purpose?

Comment: There are a bunch of lame online iPhone simulators. Aptana used to have a reasonable one but it's been deprecated. http://www.aptana.com/iphone

Comment: +1  jqplot is the new hotness.

Comment: @Yada what? are u from the jqplot dev team :)

Comment: I have recently had trouble with jqplot on an ipad3 (and presumably iphones).  I could display up to 3 plots on the ipad, but more than that caused mobile safari to crash.  Google shows that other people have had problems with jqplot crashing on the ipad as well, and with memory leaks. On the most recent version if the browser is left up with the plots showing for a day or so, the plots will no longer be displayed.  Memory leaks may be why jqplot crashes on the ipad. The developer has said he cannot fix this due to lack of ipad. I will be trying flot next to see if that has similar problems.

Comment: Having studied both for a while, I'm leaning towards Flot. jqplot does not seem to support interaction with the charts? Basically, the Flot examples impressed me a whole lot more than jqplot.

Comment: As of this date in 2014, jQPlot hasn't been updated in over a year, whereas Flot is actively updated. Also, the Flot code is much smaller (52kb vs 169kb).

Answer (score 6):

I am surprised that no one has mentioned HighCharts.

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is a comprehensive library of Javascript charting based on Jquery.

Comment: Highcharts is nice, but commercial (although not expensive compared to many things).

Answer (score 4):

One option is [jquery-visualize](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update-to-jquery-visualize-accessible-charts-with-html5-from-designing-with.html), which graphs data from a regular HTML table, so it degrades nicely without javascript

[Some examples](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/charting_v2/), and [an article about it](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update-to-jquery-visualize-accessible-charts-with-html5-from-designing-with.html):

> Accessible data visualization in HTML has always been tricky to achieve, particularly because elements such as images allow only the most basic features for providing textual information to non-visual users. A while back, we wrote an article describing a technique we came up with to use JavaScript to scrape data from an HTML table and generate charts using the HTML 5 Canvas element. The technique is particularly useful because the data for the visualization already exists in the page in structured tabular format, making it accessible to people who browse the web with a screen reader or other assistive technology.

Comment: I like this one a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/). It's open source using the MIT license, so you can do what you like to the API.

As for cross browser, I used it under all the major browers. There was a bug with Opera on filled charts, but that was an Opera canvas bug and it was fixed over a year ago. For IE, flot uses excanvas.

Comment: Thanks Nosredna.Really useful.My major development will target IE 6+.

Comment: Ouch, I pity you (and I pity your users) IE 6 is not my least favorite browser, but it is near the bottom of the heap.

Comment: @Eponymous is there **any** worst than IE6 ?

Comment: @MichelAyres There are hoarier versions of Netscape Communicator and Mosaic running on old XTerminals but you are right that for things most people will come in contact with, IE6 is probably the worst.

Answer (score 2):

I used [Rapheal](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html)
Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Zino UI Charts](http://zinoui.com/charts) is a jQuery charting library

- 15+ chart types (line, area, bar, column, pie, donut, spline, stepline, bubble, scatter, candlestick, ohlc, polar, radar, wind rose)
- cross browser
- supports SVG and HTML5 Canvas
- PHP server-wrappers
- GPL license

Answer (score 0):

I use [shieldui chart](http://www.shieldui.com/). It is very powerful and they have ASP.NET wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best is [jQuery Flot charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/), he has a good [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) *(could be better)* and even an amazing [tutorial site](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/) *(that I think is better to understand and use. the Flot chart)*

Also, he has over [1.2K questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flot). And plugins like the one for [Zoom](https://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.navigate.js?r=317)/[Navigation](https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/jquery.flot.navigationControl) and [tons of others plugins](http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/) for it

---

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is a great option too, with an excellent [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs) and [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) pages.

I don't like the [Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) that much, but is a good and "easy to use" plugin.

---

**And you can always take a look at the jQuery site page of [plugins for graphics](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/graphics/)**

Where you can always take a look in the latest list with votes and stuff.