# How to choose a web-based chart-visualization framework?

Tags: charts, visualization, web-frameworks

I want to build a website that displays data from an external databases. The data must be displayed in the form of charts, because charts are more expressive. I've never developed any websites yet, can anyone give me some advice about existing web frameworks and what are the advantages and disadvantages of them?

Which framework should I choose? The data are stored in an SQL Server. Because new data report types might be required in the future, the framework must be easy to modify and expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely subjective and there are many answers to this. With that said I'll tell you what I'd use:

You mentioned that your database is using SQL Server. I'll assume that you'll want to host your website on a windows server for sake of argument. Given that, I'd choose either ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC given that they are natural picks for a windows server hosting websites on IIS. Then I'd find myself a nice jQuery charting plugin [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201098/jquery-charting).

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I choose  ASP.NET MVC and  Highcharts according to your advices and  it works well. Thanks again!