# ASP.net with C# Drawing a line/Series of lines/Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, drawing, line

I have a web form where the user adds a schedule to a listbox.  They pick the day, the events, and the times.  Now, I want to draw a small day chart near the bottom of the page.  I want a continuous line, midnight to midnight, where depending on the event, the line is drawn on that level of the chart.

Say the user jogs from 5:00AM to 6:00AM, then takes the rest of the day off.  The line would start at midnight, draw left  to right, until it got to 05:00.  Then it would dip to the jogging level of the chart, the line would go until 06:00, then back up to the "at rest" part of the chart and draw all the way to midnight that day.

How do you draw lines on a web form in a fixed area with asp.net using c#?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using Google Charts, or another charting library and render that client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jake,

I would recommend using some charting solutions. There were some recommendations on jquery solutions [you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201098/jquery-charting)

You can also explore other vizualization frameworks like [Kendo UI - Data Viz](http://www.kendoui.com/dataviz.aspx)

Hope this helps,
-covo

Answer (score 1):

There are various charting solutions, as suggested.  Another option, if you do not require older IE browser support, is to use the HTML5 Canvas to draw.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/