# MVC4 ASP.NET AJAX Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

I´m looking for a chart component using AJAX/Jscript written above jQuery that allow me to build line, bar and pizza custom graphics. Something like jQGrid is for grids...

Any suggestions of what shall I use...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the follwoing link this is being discussed previously
[jQuery Charting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201098/jquery-charting)

Below are some famous plugins

http://www.jqplot.com/

http://www.flotcharts.org/

http://jquerychart.net/

Comment: Which one is the most "common used" ? Any advice ?

Comment: We have been using jqplot and were very good. Again it depends on chart type you need. You have most of the common chart type with jqplot.