# ColdFusion UI tags to jQuery conversion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion

I am trying to convert some code that has various ColdFusion UI tags to jQuery. I have to create a migration plan. Currently this is what I have

```
Tag             Replacement
CFApplet        ???
CFCalendar      http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
CFChart         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201098/jquery-charting
CFForm          too many to list
CFGrid          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622716/choosing-a-jquery-datagrid-plugin
CFMap           ???
CFProgressBar   http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/
CFSlider        http://jqueryui.com/slider/
CFTextArea (rich edit) ???
CFToolTip       http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/
CFTree          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710114/jquery-tree-plugin
CFWindow        http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
```

Some of the ColdFusion tags such as cfapplet and cftextarea don't seem to have a simple correspond replacement. I am particularly concerned about cfmap and cftextarea. Is there jQuery stuff that corresponds to these?

Comment: No one uses `cfapplet` and if they do, they deserve to have to deal with the CF implementation. CKEditor has a jQuery plugin version, as does TinyMCE. As for `cfmap`, the native Google Maps is actually pretty easy to use, no need for jQuery.  Keep in mind, this question might not last for long as it is 'opinion based'.

Comment: *"Is there a basic conversion chart for moving. Some of the ColdFusion tags such as cfapplet and cftextarea don't seem to have a simple correspond replacement"* No. Plugins do exist that do the same thing, but there is no chart matching the two together because there are many options for you to choose from and 90% of them are open-source/built by 3rd party developers.

Comment: James, recommend you hastily reword this as a question, and then provide your table as an answer. otherwise it'll get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple replacement libraries that we use versus the standard ColdFusion tags:

```
CFSelect     Select2 (jQuery) http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
CFTextArea   CKEditor         http://ckeditor.com/
CFWindow     colorBox         http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/
CFMap        Gmap3            http://gmap3.net/
CFForm       jQuery Validation Plugin   http://jqueryvalidation.org/
CFGrid       Tablesorter      http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/
CFTree       Dynatree         http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/
CFCalendar   Pikaday          http://dbushell.github.io/Pikaday/
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this is covered in **ColdFusion UI the Right Way**

Site summary:

> This project was created to help lead ColdFusion developers away from
>   the multiple built-in UI controls with the product. It is our belief
>   (and this will be expanded in more detail in the Introduction) that
>   these UI controls lead developers down a path that brings nothing but
>   despair and destruction. Yes, we're being overly dramatic. But at the
>   same time we've seen far too many people get screwed by using these
>   controls instead of just learning to do it the right way.
>
> This repo contains both text as well as samples you can run in your
>   local environment. All samples will work without a datasource and
>   should require no setup.

https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way