# ColdFusion built-in AJAX vs JQuery or ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, coldfusion

I was wondering what the difference is between ColdFusion's built-in AJAX functionality and using a JS framework like JQuery?

It seems that ColdFusion ships with tags that can do fancy Javascript layouts and controls e.g.`<cflayout>` and `<cfwindow>`. If it can already do this then why would one want to look at JQuery?

I'm asking this question because I have been given the task of making an internal CRM application which should have a 'rich' UI. I started investigating JQuery and ExtJS which do the fancy client-side UI work. However I also noticed that CF has similar abilities. Because I am starting from ground zero I was wondering whether to spend (a lot of) time learning JQuery or ExtJS, or cut down on my development time and just use CF's built in AJAX tools.

With some good design skills, would it not be possible to create a 'rich' application with CF's built-in AJAX controls and some fancy CSS styles?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would highly recommend not using CF's built in functions. You can find open source projects that are much better.

Comment: definitely you should leverage jquery considering it gives you much more flexibility. Simply put you can customize every single aspect of your application which is not the case with the built in functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start learning JQuery and ExtJS!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988379/coldfusion-ui-tags-to-jquery-conversion covers some of these concerns

Comment: Are the skills to use JQuery transferable to ExtJS and vice-versa? I'm not sure which one I should learn first...

Comment: Just thought I would add a link to Ben Forta's thoughts on NOT using the ColdFusion built-in functions. [When Using ColdFusion (built-in functions) No Longer Makes Sense](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to consider:

Yes, you could use CF's built-in Ajax/UI stuff to build a nice application. The downside is that doing anything outside the box of what CF has baked in is a big headache., Plus, the version of Ext JS which CF has is quite old...so getting all the goodness from the latest version (v.4.2+) is not an option, since CF doesn't have a mechanism for upgrading that library seamlessly (or freely).

As others have mentioned, you should definitely use a non-CF alternative--they are all dead-simple to integrate with CF-backend anyway, so the amount of effort required to do that vs. wrestling with tweaking the internal CF stuff is actually lesser.

Which library to use? Well, you need to seriously consider your options before jumping into one or the other. jQuery (and jQuery UI) and Bootstrap are nice for *design*...unlike Ext JS, however, they don't come baked in with uber-rich "data-aware" components (grids, trees, etc). They are more libraries than they are frameworks (like Ext JS). On the other hand, Ext JS, for your purposes, will *not* be free. Unless you plan on open-sourcing your "internal" CRM codebase, you'll likely have to commercially license the software, which is on a per-developer seat basis. I think it's well worth the cost, considering what you get, but that will have to be part of your organization's calculation if you decide to go that route.

Comment: Do you feel then that ExtJS would be a first choice for what I am trying to do? Because I am just starting out, I thought my workflow would be making the basic site in HTML, ColdFusion and CSS and then start trying to make it clever with a JS framework. Would this be the correct way to go about it?

Comment: You could use Ext JS in that way, but personally, I would suggest that you use Ext JS only if you plan on using it as *the* client side of your application. The new MVC architecture which Ext JS 4.x+ provides lends itself to building really robust, really complex JS applications. In such an approach, however, CF really becomes just an way to expose an API to the application on your server. Now personally, I think this is good and I've had a lot of success with it. However, if you're wanting to do a more conventional style website, I think Ext JS might be overkill for what you're wanting.

Comment: I suppose a conventional website will serve the purpose, but people are asking for a 'rich' UI experience so that they don't have to keep reloading pages everything they do something. It should be like a desktop experience on the web. Is this not, then, just a presentational layer thing to improve the UI (hence my thinking about adding a JS framework 'on top' of the website) or does it have to be built into the application itself?

Comment: For the kind of app you just described, Ext JS is probably a good fit. Yes, it is a presentation layer, but I would rather think of it as *the* website itself. If you use a product like Ext JS to create the client-side, ColdFusion is basically kicked out of the presentation layer altogether. CF becomes really just an API of sorts that processes the AJAX requests coming in from your client-side app. And of course, since you've completely severed CF from the client side, you actually have a very portable app, and could switch to PHP, .NET, etc. without having to change anything on the client.

Comment: The important thing I want to make sure I'm communicating, however, is that unlike libraries like jQuery/Bootstrap, Ext JS (and others) are best used as full client-side frameworks for building apps. With an Ext JS MVC-style application, for example, you can literally create a robust and complex app without writing a single line of HTML. With jQuery, you'd probably put the library on top of template code that you've already written, but with a full use of Ext JS, you'd let the framework do that work for you. This can be a huge learning curve at first, but is extremely powerful when leveraged.

Comment: And finally, with a full Ext JS app, you'd probably move away from page-to-page navigation, and instead create either one or several mini web applications that encapsulate all the functionality within a single "page" via AJAX interactions. Such a model presents some interesting challenges with how you architect your application (back button, session management, updating views based on data changes, etc), but such a model will also push you down a path of really and properly organizing your code and objects into relationships that make sense beyond the arbitrary correlation of a unique URL.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't recommend using CF's Ajax functionality. I've build internal tools using ColdFusion's built in javascript and they run very slow to say the least. Your best bet is to go with JQuery and Bootstrap. This could be a bit more difficult at first, but it would open a lot of doors down the road.

Good luck! Al